# Can we type strings with use of hex codes in c# like we type integers like that int a = 0x0000cd54;?

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex

I think this is kind of unusual thing to ask, but I need this.
Well, I know I can do this:

```
string str = "45 AC 1B 5C";
```

And then convert it into something meaningful, but what if I don't want to bother with conversion and want to set string somehow like that: `"0x00000045 0x000000AC 0x0000001B 0x0000005C"` and then it automatically becomes common characters?

Is there any way?

Comment: What's the motivation for the question?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you understand different string encodings?

Comment: I need to replace one `sequence` in huge string with another `sequence`, that contains unprintable character. Currently, I prefer to use .Replace method, instead of coding own to deal with bytes arrays, search them and modify it's length.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? You haven't answered if you understand what a string encoding is.

Comment: I understand what is different encodings, but since c# use unicode, I think it will know the meaning of some hex code.

Comment: @xxbbcc - I need this, because it needed for me. This is long to explain, but I coding the editor for some resource. There are strings that contains byte 127 (DEL), this byte becomes `space` when text loaded into RichTextBox, so I need somehow to replace it back into 127. But I can't replace all spaces to 127, so I need to replace some sequence that contains space to another sequence with 127 instead of space.

Comment: @Kosmos C# doesn't use Unicode, it uses UTF-16. It's a very different encoding and you'll have to be especially careful because of that if there's a chance your code will be used outside of English territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = "\x45 \xac \x1b \5c"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Ultimate good answer and without unneeded questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Kosmos **-1** You reply clarification requests of people with `I need this, because it needed for me. This is long to explain`, and `without unneeded questions`. Think, they don't get paid for solving your questions.

Comment: @L.B - it's up to you, I already get used to this. When peoples ask how to create files, no one asks why he need it, so when I ask how to type strings in hex codes, why is needed to know for what I need it? When peoples know the answer - they answers, when don't know - they look for bypass ways.

Comment: @Kosmos - it was not easy to understand what you are asking. I guessed and it seems I was right. The people *who are trying to help you* are asking what it is you are trying to do, they dont mean 'why', then mean 'what is you real aim'?